# What "this.data = this.data || {}" means in Memoization pattern?

Tags: javascript, memoization

I am a student studying `javascript`, and I encountered a problem while studying `memoization` pattern. This is the code :

```
Function.prototype.memoization = function(key) {
   var arg = Array.prorotype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
   this.data = this.data || {} ;    //THE code

   return this.data[key] !== undefined ?
       this.data[key] : this.data[key] = this.apply(this, arg);
};
```

For me it is shown as just `OR` operation between an array and a blank array, and I cannot understand why such code is needed.

Comment: The answers posted below are generally correct.  The only thing I will add is that it is being used as a shorthand to stand in for a more verbose `if` statement: `if (!this.data) { this.data = {}; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` operator in JavaScript can also be used for conditional evaluation since it "short circuits". If the left hand side of the operator evaluates to true, there's no need to check the right hand side.

The interpreter evaluates the left-hand side of the operator and returns the result if it evaluates to something different than false or null, otherwise the right hand side is evaluated and returned.

```
let x = 1 || 2;
// Prints 1
print(x);

let y = null || 3;
// Prints 3
print(y);
```

In your example: if there's something in `this.data` then that same information will be stored in `this.data`, otherwise an empty object is assigned.

Comment: There are other falsy values other than false and null, like 0 and empty string, which will also evaluate to false.

Answer (score 1):

This makes sure this.data has a value if it's not defined. When `this.data` is `undefined` or `null` the `this.data || {}` expression becomes `undefined || {}` (or `null || {}`)  which evaluates to `{}`

Answer (score 1):

It is for setting default value. If a given object has no value assigned to key `data`, `this.data` returns `undefined` value. `undefined` value is proned to result unexpected behaviors and errors. So we need to set default value for `data`. In this case it is an empty object `{}`. If you are familiar with `PHP`(v 7.0 or higher), it is similar to `??` notation.